# Delete subdomain from AWS Route 53 using Bash script

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I want to write a bash script to delete the subdomain name in Route 53.

I have given access to my ec2 server by using

```
$ echo "[Credentials]" > ~/.boto
$ echo "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=key" >> ~/.boto
$ echo "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=secret" >> ~/.boto
$ chmod 640 ~/.boto
```

Now,I am using `cli53 rrdelete subdomain_name CNAME` command on my ubuntu server but got

> ```
> "usage: cli53 rrdelete [-h] [-i IDENTIFIER] [--wait]
>                       zone rr [{A,AAAA,CNAME,SOA,NS,MX,PTR,SPF,SRV,TXT,ALIAS}]
> cli53 rrdelete: error: argument zone: Zone 'stagingmunnar1.bizom.in' not found"
> ```

error.
So,Kindly let me know how to use this command to delete my subdomain in AWS Route 53.

Comment: You don't need to ask people to help you, within your question. But... as it stands, you really don't have a question - you have a statement about what you want to do. And you've shown no work, so it looks like you're asking people to write you a bash script. That's not really how ServerFault works. You should show what you've done, and where you're stuck.

Comment: After giving access to my EC2 server:-        $ echo "[Credentials]" > ~/.boto
$ echo "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=key" >> ~/.boto
$ echo "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=secret" >> ~/.boto
$ chmod 640 ~/.boto...I use the command "cli53 rrdelete subdomain_name CNAME" to delete the particular subdomain...but it produces  "cli53 rrdelete: error: argument zone: Zone 'subdomain_name' not found" error...

Comment: Read the usage syntax again. There are two names that you need to supply before the record type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically *nix commands come with a manual page  try `man cli53` to see if that gives you more information than just that terse error/help message. Manual pages typically come with examples as well.

In this case I think if would know the jargon would understand what the error message is trying to tell was wrong in your command. The required options for `cli53 rrdelete` are:

- `zone` = your domainname (i.e. `bizom.in`)
- `rr` is a Resource Record or simply a (subdomain) entry in a DNS zone (either `stagingmunnar1` or `stagingmunnar1.bizom.in.`)

By convention <kbd>[</kbd>optional arguments<kbd>]</kbd> are enclosed by brackets `[]` .

You probably did:

```
cli53 rrdelete stagingmunnar1.bizom.in CNAME
```

instead of:

```
cli53 rrdelete bizom.in stagingmunnar1 CNAME
```

Comment: I was passing the wrong credentials that why I was unable to run the command which were given by you.Thanks a lot for your help.God bless you